# Как вывести список директорий, обёрнутых в квадратные скобки?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Как вывести в терминал список директорий от корня, чтобы каждая директория была обёрнута в квадратные скобки?

Пример вывода:

```
[/boot]
[/dev]
[/etc]
[/home]
```

Comment: если у вас в корне только каталоги, то: `$ for i in /*; do echo [$i]; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не выводить скрытые директории и слеш с двух сторон добавить:

```bsh
$ ls -d /*/ | sed  's/.*/[&]/'
[/bin/]                                     
[/boot/]                                    
[/cdrom/]                                   
[/dev/]                                     
[/etc/]
```

Это предполагает, что экзотические имена, содержащие новые строки, не используются.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать данную команду:

```
find /* -maxdepth 0 -type d -printf '[%p]\n'
```

Которая выведет список директорий в квадратных скобках:

```
[/boot]
[/dev]
[/etc]
[/home]
[/lost+found]
[/media]
[/mnt]
[/opt]
[/proc]
[/root]
[/run]
[/srv]
[/sys]
[/tmp]
[/usr]
[/var]
```

Спасибо пользователю @0xdb и @Fat-Zer за более кодгольфный вариант.

Comment: ради интереса, на что эти извращения с `xargs` и `paste`?

Comment: ```paste``` на случай если надо вывести всё это в одну строку, разделив директории каким-либо знаком, например ```:```, но тогда уже ```xargs``` не нужен

Comment: @Fat-Zer в принципе, да, можно изменить команду до более нормального  вида, без всяких ```paste```  и ```xargs```.

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё, готово!

Comment: раз уж `-printf` используешь, то `sed` тоже избыточен... или наоборот... и тот и другой умеет добавлять слеши и скобки... от `cd` я бы тоже избавился, но это уже факультативно...

Comment: `cd /; find * ...` - это зачем?  Как в вопросе надо так - `find / ...`.

Comment: Классно! Итог: ```find / -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf '[%p]\n'```

Comment: @0xdb, благодарю! То, что надо!

Comment: теперь вывод в ответе не соответствует команде — в таком варианте он также покажет сам корень `[/]`... если от него избавляться, то ИМХО лучший вариант — добавить `-mindepth`, но и `find /*` со своими минусами также допустим...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, пофиксил! Благодарю вас!

Answer (score 1):

для комплекта самый минимальный вариант, без вызова дополнительных программ, только средствами программы-оболочки (где *echo* часто является встроенной командой):

```
$ for i in /*/; do echo [$i]; done
[/bin/]
[/boot/]
[/dev/]
[/etc/]
[/home/]
...
```

Comment: Обязательно отмечать какой-либо ответ решением? Поскольку, любой ответ является правильным...

Comment: не обязательно.